# GORM dynamic multi-tenancy with MongoDB

Tags: grails, grails-orm, multi-tenant, grails-3.3.0

I am exploring dynamic multi tenancy in GORM with Angular project in Grails. Currently, I have the following in my application.yml

```
grails:
    gorm:
        multiTenancy:
            mode: DATABASE
            tenantResolverClass: org.grails.datastore.mapping.multitenancy.web.SubDomainTenantResolver
            connectionSourcesClass: org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.connections.MongoConnectionSources
            connectionsCollection: "myconnections"
        dataSource:
          dbCreate: create-drop
          url: 'mongodb://root:root@localhost:27017?ssl=false&authSource=admin'
```

This is in my application.yml

```
grails:
    gorm:
        multiTenancy:
            mode: DATABASE
            tenantResolverClass: org.grails.datastore.mapping.multitenancy.web.SubDomainTenantResolver
            connectionSourcesClass: org.grails.datastore.mapping.mongo.connections.MongoConnectionSources
            connectionsCollection: "myconnections"
        dataSource:
          dbCreate: create-drop
          url: 'mongodb://root:root@localhost:27017?ssl=false&authSource=admin'
```

And I have added the following in build.groovy and removed the `org.grails.plugins:hibernate5`

```
   compile "org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.4.2"
   compile 'org.grails.plugins:mongodb:6.1.2'
```

After trying this two of the following things are happening based on whether I implement the MultiTenant interface for my domain class.

1.If I implement the interface then I get the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Either class [com.track.User] is not a domain class or GORM has not been initialized correctly or has already been shutdown. Ensure GORM is loaded and configured correctly before calling any methods on a GORM entity.
```

2. If I don't implement it then everything simply goes into one database(named test) on my mongodb server.

What am I missing?

**** UPDATE ****
After creating a new project from scratch I am getting the following exception

```
Caused by: org.grails.datastore.mapping.multitenancy.exceptions.TenantNotFoundException: No tenantId found
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.multitenancy.resolvers.NoTenantResolver.resolveTenantIdentifier(NoTenantResolver.groovy:17)
    at grails.gorm.multitenancy.Tenants.currentId(Tenants.groovy:73)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEnhancer.findTenantId(GormEnhancer.groovy:270)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEnhancer.findStaticApi(GormEnhancer.groovy:296)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.currentGormStaticApi(GormEntity.groovy:1349)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.count(GormEntity.groovy:628)
    at grails.rest.RestfulController.countResources(RestfulController.groovy:275)
    at grails.rest.RestfulController.index(RestfulController.groovy:62)
    at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:94)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:91)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Uploading an example project that demonstrates the issue would be helpful

Comment: @JamesKleeh https://github.com/sapanparikh18/mongo-multitenant/tree/master While creating the example now I am getting a different error message! TenantNotFoundException: No TenantId found